# Booking honeymoon before name change

Tags: uk, passports, qatar-airways, expedia

For sake of question, we are UK based.

Myself and fiancée are looking to book our honeymoon for September this year to Singapore.  She will be taking my surname after the wedding.

The issue is that her passport, which is in her maiden name, expires in May, and we do not get married until June.  We do not want to pay to renew her current passport, and then have to pay again to change her name after the wedding.

If her passport was not due to expire, we would have just booked it in her maiden name and changed her name on the passport after the honeymoon.

If we were to book the honeymoon via Expedia, with flights via Qatar Airways, would this be safe enough to do by using her name with my surname, and then apply for the new passport after the wedding seeing as there are 2 full months between the wedding and travel date?

Comment: Not quite duplicate, as that was asking about a booking in the old name with a new passport.  This is whether we can book in a new name without a passport in that name

Comment: Are you certain that you must give the a passport at the time of booking?  Most airlines do not in my experience require this.  If your booking agent does, then the proper solution to this quandary will depend on their policies.  Have you asked them?  It is also generally possible to use a passport in a former name in connection with a legal document showing the change of name.  Obviously it would be better to have a passport in her new name rather than being stuck carrying around the marriage certificate for the next ten years, but the possibility does exist.

Comment: Is the question whether you're obligated to supply her last name to the airline on the booking website, at the time of booking? or whether you can get her post-dated name change on a new passport before travel date?

Answer (score 10):

What appears to be an official UK government web site has a [form](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/passports-for-newly-weds-and-civil-partners) for getting a (post-dated) passport in your new name up to three months *before* the ceremony. The person who will conduct the ceremony has to sign, too. [Link updated using @phoog comment]

Comment: The page for that form is https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/passports-for-newly-weds-and-civil-partners.  I looked for that page because the presence of that form on their site doesn't necessarily mean that the form is currently authorized for use.  Another advantage of the page is that it also links to the guidance, which talks a bit about the conditions of this procedure, which include that the applicant will be without a passport between the time of application and the date of the ceremony.  It also mentions restrictions that some countries place on the use of post-dated passports.

Comment: @HankyPanky: Oh look correct use of country codes.